# Yii vs Highcharts vs Ajax

Tags: ajax, yii, highcharts

here is a part of my view:

```
<?php
echo CHtml::dropDownList('al_ev_id', $model->al_ev_id,$listaDateAl,
                              array(
                                 'ajax' => array(
                                 'type'=>'POST',
                                 'url'=>CController::createUrl('stat/ajaxStoricoSubDetails'),
                                 'update'=>'#storicoSubDetails',
                                 ),
                                 'class' => 'rowform',
                        ));
...
?>
<div id="storicoSubdetails">
...
<?php
$this->Widget('ext.highcharts.HighchartsWidget', array(
   'options'=>array(
      'title' => array('text' => 'A title'),
      'xAxis' => array(
         'categories' => $model->streamLabel
      ),
      'yAxis' => array(
         'title' => array('text' => 'another title')
      ),
      'series' => array(
         array('name' => $model->labelGraph, 'data' => $model->streamData)
      )
   )
));     

?>
...
</div>
```

the controller in the action 'ajaxStoricoSubDetails' reload the same $this->Widget('ext.highcharts.HighchartsWidget' etc, etc

the objective of this code is to update the starting x-value of the graph, modifying it with the dropdown

**and here is my problem:**

the first rendering of highcharts graph is ok; but, when I change the value in the DropDown, thus starting the ajax part, graph is not rendered

highcharts return an error 16 code, that means

**Highcharts already defined in the page**

in fact in the second rendering code (the ajax fired part) I find

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

that I think is the problem

is there any way to avoid this

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

*It's not the best long term solution, but...*

If `<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>` is at the top of your page now, move it in `<div id="storicoSubdetails">` instead.

That way the script reference should be overwritten when the ajax stuff reloads everything in the `storicoSubdetails` div, and you will only have 1 script reference on the page.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, in fact my problem is to convince Yii not to automatically put two `<script ... highcart.js` stuff, inside the code